# MS Access Criteria Query

Tags: ms-access

How can I give greater than or less than function in criteria field in design view on MS Access?

I tried to give "greater than 13" in the criteria field, but it's not working.

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Examples-of-query-criteria-3197228c-8684-4552-ac03-aba746fb29d8

Answer (score 0):

In criteria field you should enter :

```
> 13 greater than
13 equals to 13
< 13 less than 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 alternatives.
1) In design view you have several rows. Two of them say: 'Criteria' and 'or'
Then set:
Criteria: <= 13
Or: >13

2) Make an IIf(x <13,1,0) and in the criteria you filter with 1 or 0 depending what you want to filter